# Geocoding and SRID - can't get desired SRID

Tags: qgis, python, google-maps, geocoding, srid

I want to geocode a set of addresses with GoogleMaps, store the results in a different SRID in a PostGIS table and then project it in QGIS over a layer with the identical SRID. So far, it has been a complete mess since I succeed in geocoding but can't change the SRID so I can't have overlapping layers.

I break the process in steps:

1. Geocode addresses
2. Add column *mygeometry* with a different SRID (2100) than the geocoder's usual (GoogleMaps' Mercator) and store it all at my PostGIS table as *tableA*
3. Open QGIS, add layers from *tableA* and *tableB* (which is a map of the country).

Here's the Python code for geocoding and storing (I note that *mygeometry* column has already been created as a *geometry(MultiPoint,2100)* column:

```
from geopy import geocoders    
g = geocoders.GoogleV3()    
for i in range (1,tableAlength):
    location, (latitude, longitude) = g.geocode(tableA.ix[i][1])
    if location:
        mygeometry ='SRID=2100;MULTIPOINT(%r %r)' % (longitude, latitude)
        mystring=("UPDATE tableA SET latitude="
                  +str(latitude) +" WHERE tableA_id='"+str(i)+"';")
        db.alters(mystring)
        mystring=("UPDATE tableA SET longitude="
                  +str(longitude) +" WHERE tableA_id='"+str(i)+"';")
        db.alters(mystring)
        mystring=("UPDATE tableA SET mygeometry='"
                  +str(mygeometry)+"' WHERE tableA_id='"+str(i)+"';")
        db.alters(mystring)
        i=i+1
    else:
        i=i+1
```

I have tried it also with Nominatim and no success. The question is why it does not store my points in the new SRID.

Comment: I edited my post in order to set one specific  question. I`m taking the tour now and not before since I thought it`s the same philosophy as in the rest stackoverflow. Thx for your comment. The SRID issue has really troubled me.

Comment: Note that you are generally not allowed to use google geocoding except for with google maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10.

Comment: I see. Good to know. Thank you very much for the heads-up.